# how to create a label with a link that will open in safari?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I need to give a UILabel wich will contain a link. I need to make it that way, that when the link is touched, it will open up in safari. I tried with a web view but it does load. That leads to another question. I made a Ui View with this code:

```
//Stage 1

  [_viewWeb setDelegate:self];

   NSString *fullURL = @"https://www.facebook.com/pages/Restauracja-Hawełka/197503186962278";

   //Stage 2
   NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];

   //Stage 3
    NSURLRequest *requestObj =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Stage 4
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}



-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [_labelLoading setHidden:NO];

}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [_labelLoading setHidden:YES];

}
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"ERROR VIEW NOT LOADED");}
```

and everything is declared in the `ViewController.h`.

But i get the View did not Load message all the time... What can i do? Thanks in advance! Julian

Comment: Can't you do a simple button?

Comment: Take a look at [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel). It gives you the freedom to add links in labels, and also, do whatever action you wish to perform on selection of those links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their are many ways to do so, best way is to use a UITextVeiw and add following properties, now it will be turned to link and whenever you give link as a text for textview it will become tapable and user will be switched to safari on tapping that link:

```
textview.editable = NO;
textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

If you do not want to display whole link, then you can just add a UITapgeasture recogonizer and add following line on its action:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.daledietrich.com"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

With label, you would need to tag it and go through `touchbegan...` events which is very ugly.

Instead, you should use a button with clear background.
Connect its clicked event to some custom method of yours say "launchBrowser"

in launchBrowser: (NSString *) urlString

```
-(void) launchBrowser
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

If you want to do all this inside a Webview and launch link in Safari, you need to override 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest UIWebviewDelegate method like this

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a UILabel with a link, what you can do is create a button with a clear background :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    UIButton *linkButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,40)];

    NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your Link Title"];
    [title addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [title length])];
    [title addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [title length])];
    [linkButton setAttributedTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [linkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openBrowser) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:linkButton];
    ....
}

- (void)openBrowser{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURL"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are  custom controls [Here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sttweetlabel) and [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tttattributedlabel)

you can use this control many live apps already using this control.